How to Project Test Data onto a Trained NMF Model in R?
I am working with the NMF package in R and have successfully trained an Non Negative Matrix Factorisation model on my training dataset. Now, I would like to project a new test dataset onto this trained NMF model to obtain the corresponding coefficient matrix (or basis components) for the test data.
Is there a straightforward way to achieve this in R?
My ultimate goal is to validate the NMF solution within a separate classification model. Specifically, I plan to train the classifier on basis components) from the NMF model applied to the training data, and then use the classifier to predict the basis components of the test set.
Any guidance on how to correctly project the test data onto the NMF model and obtain these components would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a brief logic of what I have.
Here is an example of the starting point witha. reprex

library(NMF)


# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate synthetic training data
# 50 samples, 20 features
train_data <- matrix(runif(1000, 0, 1), nrow = 50, ncol = 20)
test_data <- matrix(runif(400, 0, 1), nrow = 20, ncol = 20)

# Train the NMF model on the training data
rank <- 3  # Number of basis components
res_nmf_train <- NMF::nmf(train_data + 0.0001, rank, nrun = 10, seed = 123456)

# Extract the basis (W) matrix
W_train <- basis(res_nmf_train)
# Extract the coefficient (H) matrix for the training data
H_train <- coef(res_nmf_train)


I want to be able to project test_data to the model space of res_nmf_train
I would then train a classifier model on train_data features and test how well it can classify classes in the test_set, based on its basis values (i.e. W_test)
